# Como animar a disposição de divs e legenda, ao fazer hover num destes elementos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css3

Estou a criar um site, pediram me para fazer uma brincadeira  na parte da equipa. Conforme esta imagem, quando se faz :hover numa das partes, todo o texto e imagem se ordenam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei como descalçar esta bota, pois `javascript` não é o meu forte. Gostaria que me pudessem ajudar.

[Foto recortada](http://we.tl/B0ey4NSoU0)

O meu `HTML` é:

```
<div class="equipa_membro">
  <div class="equipa_foto equipa_foto1">
    <div class="equipa_ft_tr equipa_ft2_tr1"></div>
    <div class="equipa_ft_tr equipa_ft2_tr2"></div>
    <div class="equipa_ft_tr equipa_ft2_tr3"></div>
    <div class="equipa_ft_tr equipa_ft2_tr4"></div>
    <div class="equipa_ft_tr equipa_ft2_tr5"></div>
    <div class="equipa_ft_tr equipa_ft2_tr6"></div>
  </div>
  <h5 class="nome_equipa1">oNem od bmoerM</h6>
  <p class="funcao_equipa2">ãnuonçF edsepDamehane</p>
</div>
```

O meu `CSS`:

```
.equipa_membro {height: 320px; margin-top: 50px;}
.equipa_foto {width: 282px; height: 244px; margin: 0 auto;}
.equipa_ft_tr {width: 141px; height: 122px;}

.equipa_ft1_tr1 {background: url(images/foto1.png); position: absolute; margin: 0px 0px; }
.equipa_ft1_tr2 {background: url(images/foto2.png); position: absolute; margin: 0px 70px; z-index: 1000;}
.equipa_ft1_tr3 {background: url(images/foto3.png); position: absolute; margin: 0px 141px;}
.equipa_ft1_tr4 {background: url(images/foto4.png); position: absolute; margin: 122px 0px;}
.equipa_ft1_tr5 {background: url(images/foto5.png); position: absolute; margin: 122px 70px; z-index: 1000;}
.equipa_ft1_tr6 {background: url(images/foto6.png); position: absolute; margin: 122px 141px;}
```

Comment: @Avelino, tem uma parte de sua edição que não concordo. O assunto está sendo discutido [neste Meta post](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201) (tem uma resposta minha que explica o que discordo).

Comment: Eu, não vejo problema algum na edição do Avelino, @brasofilo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui ficam duas alternativas:

### #1 - usando CSS transitions para o url da imagem de fundo

```
var linkImagens;
var divImagens;
$('.equipa_membro').hover(function () {
    divImagens = $(this).find('.equipa_ft_tr');
    linkImagens = divImagens.map(function () {
        return {
            top: $(this).css('margin-top'),
            left: $(this).css('margin-left')
        };
    })
    var qtdImagens = divImagens.length;
    divImagens.each(function (i) { // re-organizar os links
        var imagemAusar = (i + 2) < qtdImagens ? i + 2 : i - qtdImagens + 2;
        $(this).css('margin', linkImagens[imagemAusar]);

    });
    
        $(this).find('.nome_equipa1').toggle(); // mostrar o que está invisivel e esconder o que está visivel
        $(this).find('.funcao_equipa1').toggle(); // mostrar o que está invisivel e esconder o que está visivel
}, function () {
    divImagens.each(function (i) {
        $(this).css('margin', linkImagens[i]);
    });
        $(this).find('.nome_equipa1').toggle();
        $(this).find('.funcao_equipa1').toggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.equipa_ft_tr{
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/v7fxW/)

### #2 - Usando CSS transitions para a posição(margin) das imagens de fundo

```
var linkImagens;
var divImagens;
$('.equipa_membro').hover(function () {
    divImagens = $(this).find('.equipa_ft_tr');
    linkImagens = divImagens.map(function () {
        return {
            top: $(this).css('margin-top'),
            left: $(this).css('margin-left')
        };
    })
    var qtdImagens = divImagens.length;
    divImagens.each(function (i) {
        var imagemAusar = i >= 2 ? i - 2 : i + 4;
        $(this).css('margin-top', linkImagens[imagemAusar].top);
        $(this).css('margin-left', linkImagens[imagemAusar].left);
    });
    $(this).find('.nome_equipa1').toggle();
    $(this).find('.funcao_equipa1').toggle();
}, function () {
    divImagens.each(function (i) {
        $(this).css('margin-top', linkImagens[i].top);
        $(this).css('margin-left', linkImagens[i].left);
    });
    $(this).find('.nome_equipa1').toggle();
    $(this).find('.funcao_equipa1').toggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.equipa_ft_tr {
    transition: margin 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/k3PWg/)

---

Em ambas as sugestões que apresento em cima reordenei as imagens para fazer o javascript mais simples. Assim as imagens estão :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Para além desta alteração, uso também este código HTML para mostrar/esconder o texto certo:

```
<h5 class="nome_equipa1">oNem od bmoerM</h5>
<h5 class="nome_equipa1" style="display:none">Nome do Membro</h5>
<p class="funcao_equipa1">ãnuonçF edsepDamehane</p>
<p class="funcao_equipa1" style="display:none">Função Desempenhada</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Isto resolve o problema. Só tem um pequeno senão, é que o efeito está ao contrario, a imagem deveria aparecer desmontada, e ficar montada após o hover. Estou a tentar fazer isso, só que não consigo fazer com que as peças desmontadas fiquem com a ordem que está aqui, demo do a que a imagem montada fique correcta.

Comment: @user3216077, prefer a solução 1 ou 2?

Comment: A solução 2 é mesmo a que pretendo. Obrigado :)

Comment: @user3216077: __http://jsfiddle.net/sJa8B/__

Comment: Muito Bom! Obrigado! :D

Comment: Descobri que apenas a parte do texto funciona nos browsers Firefox e IE. No Chrome tudo funciona. Já coloquei os prefixos no CSS, e não funciona na mesma. Penso que o problema esteja no javascript.

Comment: @user3216077, aqui fica uma versão para o FF e IE também. Pensava que o jQuery normalizava isso, mas não. Teste este: __http://jsfiddle.net/k3PWg/__

Comment: Muito obrigado! É mesmo isto! Cheers :D

Comment: @user3216077, fico contente de ter ajudado. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Coloque o seguinte no HTML. O `max-width` é necessário pois sem ele é como se o texto ocupasse toda a tela horizontalmente:

```
<h5 id="texto" style="max-width: 150px" class="nome_equipa1 texto">oNem od bmoerM</h6>
<p id="texto2" style="max-width: 150px" class="funcao_equipa2 texto">ãnuoçF edsepDamehane</p>
<img src="imgembaralhada.jpg" id="image2" />
<img src="imgnormal.jpg" id="image1" />
```

E o seguinte no JavaScript. Não se esqueça de colocar o link do script jQuery `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Colocando o mouse sobre o texto(mousemove)
    $('#texto').on("mousemove", function(){
        $(this).text("Nome Do Membro");
    })
    //Retirando o mouse sobre o texto(mouseout)
    $('#texto').on("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).text("oNem oD bmoerM");
    })
    //Colocando o mouse sobre o texto(mousemove)
    $('#texto2').on("mousemove", function(){
        $(this).text("Função Desempenhada");
    })
    //Retirando o mouse sobre o texto(mouseout)
    $('#texto2').on("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).text("ãnuoçF edsepDamehane");
    })
    //Colocando o mouse sobre o texto(mousemove)
    $('#image2').on("mousemove", function(){
        $(this).attr("src","imgnormal.jpg");
    })
    //Retirando o mouse sobre o texto(mouseout)
    $('#image1').on("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).attr("src","imgmbaralhada.jpg");
    })
})
```

Comment: Obrigado! A parte do texto está resolvida. Na  parte da imagem gostaria de uma solução, em que esta teria varias div's cada uma como uma parte da imagem como background. E que ao fazer hover no texto ou na respectiva imagem, elas mudassem para a posição correcta.

Comment: assim eu até poderia resolver se você disponibilizasse as imagens recortadas

Comment: vou já tratar disso. passo já uma sprite. obrigado!

Comment: esté aqui a foto recortada http://we.tl/B0ey4NSoU0. obrigado! :)

Comment: Cara você queria as imagens se movimentando até chegar na foto normal ,né?

Comment: Sim. As divs com as imagens como background, movimentadas até a forma normal.